# What to do to improve my skill and knowledge on javascript?

Tags: javascript

Currently I've finished studying the book name "Beginning JavaScript 3rd Edition", so I just wonder what should be my next step in order to strengthen myself on using and manipulating this language?

Besides, how can I improve myself in programming in JavaScript? Is it by thinking something cool myself, and start coding it? Or googling around the internet to find some task and question offered?

Is there any book that teaches the correct method of coding? Thank you

Comment: But I think I'm not really know to what extent javascript could perform,like could it possibly code a game??I know javascript is not a full fledge language like c++ and java,so with all this doubt,whenever I try to think of something to code,I will started to think,the stuff in my head,is it possible to be accomplished by javascript??This is what I'm facing right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One recommended resource would be
http://eloquentjavascript.net/index.html

It is a combination online tutorial + online book

After that, it depends on whether you want to focus on clientside or serverside JS.

Have a look through http://howtonode.org/
for Serverside.

I would recommend that you avoid relying on a javascript library until you are able to make a good assessment of its quality. And pick YUI3 once you can ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it by thinking something cool
>   myself,and start coding it?

yes - think of something that would be funny/cool to code and try to do that (and, of course, ask mr. google if you get to a problem somewhere)

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at "Javascript: The Good Parts", Douglas Crockford, O'Rielly & Yahoo Press:

http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748

Answer (score 0):

Watch the [Crockford on JavaScript](https://www.crockford.com/javascript/) videos.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you check out [Douglas Crockford's](http://javascript.crockford.com/) JavaScript site for some quality articles on style and usage of the language itself. On top of that you should be constantly coding in it, look for interesting problems to solve and implement solutions using the techniques you have picked up.

As an aside I would also say that if you're looking to truly go further with the language and not just "get stuff done", stay away from jQuery etc for now until you have a good understanding of how it is likely to be working under the hood -- once you have this understanding though it'd be worth picking it up purely for efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio allows you to develop mobile applications using JavaScript for all platforms. You can try your skills there